# biblatex-apa: sentence case not working

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, capitalization

Biblatex-Apa should automatically print titles in the reference list in sentence case, but for some reason it doesn't work (note the lowercase A after the colon):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, natbib=true, firstinits=true, uniquename=init]{biblatex} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{filecontents}{case.bib}

@ARTICLE{Saetre2010,
  author = {Saetre, Peter and Lundmark, Per and Wang, August and Hansen, Thomas
    and Rasmussen, Henrik B. and Djurovic, Srdjan and Melle, Ingrid and
    Andreassen, Ole A. and Werge, Thomas and Agartz, Ingrid and Hall,
    Hakan and Terenius, Lars and Jonsson, Erik G.},
  title = {The Tryptophan Hydroxylase 1 ({TPH1}) Gene, Schizophrenia Susceptibility,
    and Suicidal Behavior: A Multi-Centre Case-Control Study and Meta-Analysis},
  journal = {American Journal of Medical Genetics, Part B: Neuropsychiatric Genetics},
  year = {2010},
  volume = {153B},
  pages = {387--396},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{case.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I doubt the biblatex routine for sentence casing knows about colons like this. Really, you should put what is after the colon in a "SUBTITLE" field.

Comment: I updated the package today, but it worked using version 1.7

Comment: @dieAnne. `\MakeSentenceCase` down-cases all letters after the first one. This hasn't changed since 1.7. If you want to keep the first word after colons capitalized, wrap it in braces: `Behavior: {A}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Audrey you should put the second part in the entry `subtitle`. The separator between title and subtitle is a colon. So your example can modified as follows:

```
@ARTICLE{Saetre2010,
  author = {Saetre, Peter and Lundmark, Per and Wang, August and Hansen, Thomas
    and Rasmussen, Henrik B. and Djurovic, Srdjan and Melle, Ingrid and
    Andreassen, Ole A. and Werge, Thomas and Agartz, Ingrid and Hall,
    Hakan and Terenius, Lars and Jonsson, Erik G.},
  title = {The Tryptophan Hydroxylase 1 ({TPH1}) Gene, Schizophrenia Susceptibility,
    and Suicidal Behavior},
  subtitle={A Multi-Centre Case-Control Study and Meta-Analysis},
  journal = {American Journal of Medical Genetics, Part B: Neuropsychiatric Genetics},
  year = {2010},
  volume = {153B},
  pages = {387--396},
}
```

[image]